# How do you highlight code in a <pre> block?

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting

Is there a way to highlight code syntax in a `<pre>` block?

In this [post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/7188/matlab-code-demonstrating-use-of-fft-fast-fourier-transform), I had originally inserted my code using a `<pre>` block, but the code was not highlighted. After indenting every line by four characters the highlighting worked. I would include an example here, but I couldn't get highlighting to work on [Code Review Meta](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The highlighting will work if you use `<pre><code>` instead of just `<pre>`.

However it is preferred that you use the regular markdown syntax for code samples (i.e. indent by four spaces). There's a button in the formatting toolbar (the one with the {}) as well as a keyboard shortcut (ctrl+k) to do this for you, so you don't need to indent every line by hand.